# Left (or right) border in Apple's Pages

Tags: pages, text, text-editor, formatting

I am writing a Pages (5.5.3) document for my Diploma thesis.

I want to create a paragraph style for source code that has a colored border only on one side. Unfortunately, Pages gives me a limited number of options to choose from:

[image: Limited positioning of the border in Apple's Pages]

Is there any solution for achieveing the following style (notice the blue and gray left borders):

[image: A slide from Apple's WWDC presentation on "Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift"]
(BTW, this is a slide from an Apple presentation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with paragraph styles, no. You can do this with a single cell table which can be inlined and have a left border style different to the others.